# How to delete associated object from cascade="all-delete-orphan" in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In hbm file :--

I could not able to delete the product object from customer table. 
If I could change the relation with cascade="all" then I could able to delete.

But It will effect on other table.

```
  <key column="id_product"/>

  <map-key-many-to-many class="info" column="id_info"/>

  <one-to-many class="customer"/>

</map>
```

Comment: Not a proper definition of the problem. Nobody is able to understand what you are trying do.  All of these are simply fraud votes in addition to your previous question. Customers may be associated with orders, not directly with products. What type of relationship is this?